# Setting up ultrawide (3440x1440) monitor on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display-resolution, monitor, xrandr

I am trying to setup ubuntu properly on ultrawide monitor.
What have I done so far:

1. I have run:

   ```
   xrandr
   ```

   and found out that my connected monitor is `HDMI-0`:

   ```
   HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+258+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 333mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00
   ...
   ```
2. Then I have run:

   ```
   gtf 3440 1440 60
   ```

   to find my `Modeline` for the `3440x1440` resolution that I want is and got this:

   ```
     # 3440x1440 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 89.40 kHz; pclk: 419.11 MHz
     Modeline "3440x1440_60.00" 419.11  3440 3688 4064 4688  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
3. Next is to add that new mode:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode MODELINE GOES HERE
   ```

   which is in my case:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00" 419.11  3440 3688 4064 4688  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync
   ```
4. Then I added the mod with:

   ```
   xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 3440x1440_60
   ```

   Now, when I go to displays, I can find that mod on my ultrawide monitor
5. After that I have run:

   ```
   xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 3440x1440_60
   ```

   and the monitor goes black, and I have to blindly type previous resolution to get it back.

The same happens if I select it from the Displays settings.

I am using Asus Laptop model a54h

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your precise steps helped me setup my own monitor, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps above are correct. My laptop uses an AMD Radeon HD 7470M 1GB and the maximum digital resolution is `2560 x 1600`. That is why I get a black screen when I try to set it above it.

Comment: Yesterday I tested 2560x1440 with onboard intel, and it does not require custom modelines to start working. I think you also do not really need them.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that have this same issue with an ultra-wide resolution on Ubuntu, do this:

1. Verify your graphics card can support the resolution by just
   googling the model # of your graphics card & "max resolution"
2. Use the proper cable, displayport is the best option, HDMI is the second
   best option.
3. Make sure you are using a video cable with no adapters.  In other
   words, if your laptop has display port, dont use a display port to
   HDMI adapter.  This was my issue.  Once I used a straight display
   port-to-display port, everything worked flawlessly.
4. If you have a non-Intel graphics card, then look into downloading the
   Ubuntu version of those drivers.

Good Luck

Comment: > HDMI is the second best option --- what about USB-C ?

Answer (score 0):

You created newmode named "3440x1440_60.00"

> xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"

And tried to addmode called HDMI-0 3440x1440_60

> xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 3440x1440_60

Names dont match `3440x1440_60`!=`3440x1440_60.00`

However, although the option of 3440x1440 appears in the settings, system still returns to lower after applying it :/