# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) does not detect higher refresh rates on external monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 22.04

**Premise**: *like many other users, I have also encountered the following issue which has already been documented here: [Can't use Wayland with Nvidia 510 drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403854/cant-use-wayland-with-nvidia-510-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts?newreg=22493a2ede0a458d98afa08478176478) although I am unsure whether it can be related to the issue in this post (i.e. whether I would not have run into issues with refresh rates if Wayland was working correctly as it should be the default with 22.04)*

I completed a vanilla installation of the latest stable Ubuntu LTS (22.04) on a dual-boot (Windows 11) and dual-monitor setup (native 4k 60hz and external 3440x1440 100hz) and I have since been unable to select refresh rates higher than 50hz on my external monitor:
[Displays settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drXxY.png) [NVIDIA settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzDSK.png)

I have already installed all of the proprietary drivers suggested during the Ubuntu installation process, including the latest NVIDIA 510.x drivers for [my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jASOH.png), I also use high-bandwidth HDMI cables that have always allowed to operate the external monitor at 100hz on Windows 11 without issue

I have noticed that past Ubuntu versions exhibited similar behaviors for some users with regards to external monitors, however I have been unable to use their solutions. In particular, I have tried the following:

- editing `etc/environment` as detailed here: [Dual monitors setup capped at 60hz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252986/dual-monitors-setup-capped-at-60hz)
- manually adding a suitable display profile with `xrandr` for my external HDMI-0 output: [Setting up ultrawide (3440x1440) monitor on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207228/setting-up-ultrawide-3440x1440-monitor-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Some helpful debugging information:

- `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 335mm
   3440x1440     49.99*+
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.02 +
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

- `cvt 3440 1440 100` output:

```
# 3440x1440 99.99 Hz (CVT) hsync: 152.68 kHz; pclk: 728.00 MHz
Modeline "3440x1440_100.00"  728.00  3440 3728 4104 4768  1440 1443 1453 1527 -hsync +vsync
```

- `gtf 3440 1440 100` output:

```
  # 3440x1440 @ 100.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 152.50 kHz; pclk: 729.56 MHz
  Modeline "3440x1440_100.00"  729.56  3440 3728 4112 4784  1440 1441 1444 1525  -HSync +Vsync
```

- execute `xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_100.00"  728.00  3440 3728 4104 4768  1440 1443 1453 1527 hsync +vsync`
- `xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 3440x1440_100.00` output:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

- relevant section of `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer X34 P"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 140.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 3440x1440_100 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

*Kindly let me know of any additional required reproductory steps or output snippets that might help diagnose my problem here*

Comment: Usually, if you change your session to `xorg` you would be able to select higher refresh rates than on wayland.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404070/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-does-not-detect-higher-refresh-rates-on-exter#comment2438231_1404070

but I am already running x11, indeed another problem is that I am also unable to setup Wayland currently (which should have been default no less with 22.04), please read the P.S. in my original post or go here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403854/cant-use-wayland-with-nvidia-510-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts?newreg=22493a2ede0a458d98afa08478176478